# Implement interfaces via Generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have following interfaces

```
public interface IReport<TInput, TOutput>
{
    List<TOutput> GenerateReport(TInput input); 
}


public interface IReport<TOutput>
{
    List<TOutput> GenerateReport();
}
```

But now I want to have following interface

```
public interface IReport<TInput, TOutput>
{
    TOutput GenerateReport(TInput input); 
}
```

Is it possible to have like this ?

Thanks

Comment: BoltClock♦ I have duplicate public interface IReport<TInput, TOutput> everything is sitting in the same namespace

Comment: Ah, I thought you were replacing one with the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible because you already have an `IReport<TInput, TOutput>` interface defined. And you can't move the `TOutput GenerateReport(TInput input);` to the first interface because it already provides a method with the same name and same input arguments. The output arguments are not taken into account when doing overloading method resolution.

But given the output arguments of your method I would simply use more meaningful names:

```
public interface IReport<TInput, TOutput>
{
    List<TOutput> GenerateReports(TInput input);
    TOutput GenerateReport(TInput input);
}
```

Comment: I don't need them in all implementations because of it i have interfaces with only one functions in them

Comment: @NightWalker, in this case I am afraid that what you are trying to achieve is not possible. You cannot have 2 interfaces with the same name and same generic arguments. You will have to rethink your design.

Comment: Is it possible to combine both interfaces into one , and in generics specify what I want ?

Comment: @NightWalker, no, because as I already stated in my answer you cannot have 2 methods with the same name and same arguments in the same class/interface that differ only by return type. Method overloading polymorphism in .NET doesn't take into account return types.

Comment: @ Darin Dimitrov , In my last question I meant , to have only one interface and by Generics specify do I want list or not .

Comment: @NightWalker, you can do this with input parameters. Not with output.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, you could even implement them with the same class. :)

However, you'll need to rename the second IReport because you already have one with that name.

If I were you, I'd move the method declaration from the new interface to the old one.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two interfaces with the same name and same number of parameters. Note that you can't simply differentiate them with constraints.

Clearly you can change your old interface to your new specifications.